# Connection between method of Lagrange multipliers and KKT conditions?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I understand that in general, the KKT conditions are not sufficient for optimality. However, if the primal problem is a convex optimization problem, then the KKT conditions are sufficient for optimality (given smoothness of functions).

I'm trying to understand how this relates to the method of Lagrange multipliers that is typically taught in Calculus. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) doesn't seem to mention anything about convexity in regards to this method. I thought the KKT conditions were supposed to generalize this method, but maybe I am confused. Can someone explain the relationship?

Comment: The KKT-conditions become the method of Lagrange multipliers of no inequality constraints are given.

Comment: But for KKT to imply optimality, we need the primal problem to be convex. Does this same requirement hold for the method of Lagrange multipliers? i.e. does the method of Lagrange multipliers work for non-convex functions?

Comment: For both methods, you have the following: Optimality implies existence of multipliers if a CQ is satisfied. Existence of multipliers implies optimality if the problem is convex.